# How to expect empty reactive form in Angular 7 - Karma

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I created a clear method to clear my atual form.

```
this.myForm.reset();
```

Now I´m testing it, i.e., when  clear is triggered form is clear. I tried:

```
//set value and then triggered event
    component.myForm.get('field1.field2').setValue('data');
    component.clear();
```

Until this phase everything is good. I just want to test the expected value:

```
   expect(component.myForm.get('field1.field2')).toBe(''); //NOT WORKING!

   expect(component.myForm.get('field1.field2')).toEqual('');//NOT WORKING!
```

How to do this in best way possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you need to compare it with the value of the form field, using (.value), like that:

```
expect(component.myForm.get('field1.field2').value).toEqual('');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Perfect. It is a way of toEqual have null and empty values?

Comment: Yep, you have a different ways to check it:

toBeNull:

(expect(component.myForm.get('field1.field2').value).toBeNull())

Also you have more stuff to check if you want (toBeDefined, toBeTruthy, toContain, toEqual, toThrow, etc)

Here you have some examples, of how to use it (https://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction)